# php...creating website showing table from database and advance search option

Tags: php

I want to create a website which shows a table from my database with advanced search (more than one search box) to sort out the correct entry. Please help me out.

I already tried a program by single search box using an `if` condition. I want to know if two conditions are there. How can I post two search fields at same time?

Comment: we can't help if you don't let us know what you've tried (by sharing the code) and also what the specific issue is.

Comment: Hey, What have you tried till now? can you add some code?

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please step first to [HELP center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), then visit [GET started](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252149/how-does-a-new-user-get-started-on-stack-overflow), and finally, read [How to Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide a [MCVE : Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Can you share some code ? what have you tried so far ?

Answer (score 0):

This question is way too broad to be answered, you should go look up some tutorials that answers to your needs, and then work on fusing these tutorials together, creating your desired site.

To do the SQL part, looking up prepared statements is essential, and to do the advanced search I am sure there are alot of advanced search tutorials made with JavaScript or JQuery; or there might even be a plugin or two that you can install.

Stack Overflow is for answering questions, but not developing entire websites, especially not when the description is vague

Answer (score 0):

**First of all** I think you need to follow a tutorial step by step, and when you have issues that are not resolved in the tutorial you can happily post them here and the SO community will help you gladly.

Try something like this: https://www.sitepoint.com/php-amp-mysql-1-installation/

**Second**, if you need an example of a table populated with data from your database in simple PHP + HTML format (no libraries, no nothing), this could be a starter:

```
    <?php
    $getMessages = 'SELECT * FROM tab_messages';
    $qGetMessages = mysql_query($getMessages) or die ('Error in '.$getMessages.mysql_error());
    ?>
    <div id="tableDiv">
        <table>
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>name</th>
                <th>surname</th>
                <th>message</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <?php while ($rsGetMessages = mysql_fetch_object($qGetMessages)) { ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?= $rsGetMessages->name ?></td>
                    <td><?= $rsGetMessages->surname ?></td>
                    <td><?= $rsGetMessages->text ?></td>
                </tr>
            <?php } ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

In this little example we are just getting *messages* from the database and are showing them in our table.

For further information I recommend you to:

1. Try coding something
2. Post a question with code examples and specific issues (not generic)
3. Before posting a question search the net for a solution, others may have had your issues too

Hope it helped, have a nice day! ;)